# App Widget in Android with network connection

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I am trying to develop an AppWidget with network data. *So far I have an application (up and running) with a custom `AsyncTaskLoader` (gets URL gives parsed data) to loaders inside my fragments. There is no cache or db to save that data.
My best practice will be to use some of the existing network+parsing classes-functionalities if this is possible.*

Searching through many examples and tutorials I either found simple offline widgets or other with content providers and observer. None of them use network connection.

1. Can I have a widget which gets data from online json and not content resolver / provider? Any such example or guide will be really helpful!
2. My app supports 2.0 and above. From my research I found that I have to implement 2 widgets Android 3+ and lower. Is there any other simpler way to avoid double coding?

Thanks in advance!